# Python textwrap and Reset count after everyline

Tags: python, python-3.x, computer-science

Hello everyone i have an issue with this problem, the problem is i need to reset the count after every line in the file, i put a comment so you can see where i want to reset the count.

The program is suppose to cut each line after every specified lineLength.

```
def insert_newlines(string, afterEvery_char):
    lines = []
    for i in range(0, len(string), afterEvery_char):
        lines.append(string[i:i+afterEvery_char])
        string[:afterEvery_char] #i want to reset here to the beginning of every line to start count over
    print('\n'.join(lines))

def main():
    filename = input("Please enter the name of the file to be used: ")
    openFile = open(filename, 'r')
    file = openFile.read()
    lineLength = int(input("enter a number between 10 & 20: "))

    while (lineLength < 10) or (lineLength > 20) :
        print("Invalid input, please try again...")
        lineLength = int(input("enter a number between 10 & 20: "))

    print("\nYour file contains the following text: \n" + file + "\n\n") # Prints original File to screen
    print("Here is your output formated to a max of", lineLength, "characters per line: ")

    insert_newlines(file, lineLength)
main()
```

Ex. If a file has 3 lines like this with each line having 20 chars

```
andhsytghfydhtbcndhg 
andhsytghfydhtbcndhg
andhsytghfydhtbcndhg
```

after the lines are cut it should look like this

```
andhsytghfydhtb
cndhg
andhsytghfydhtb
cndhg
andhsytghfydhtb
cndhg
```

i want to RESET the count after every line in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your problem, but from your comments it appears you simply want to cut the input string (file) to lines lineLength long.  That is already done in your insert_newlines(), no need for the line with comment there.

However, if you want to output lines meaning strings ending with newline char that should be no more than lineLength long, then you could simply read the file like this:

```
lines = []
while True:
    line = openFile.readline(lineLength)
    if not line:
        break
    if line[-1] != '\n':
        line += '\n'
    lines.append(line)
print(''.join(lines))
```

or alternatively:

```
lines = []
while True:
    line = openFile.readline(lineLength)
    if not line:
        break
    lines.append(line.rstrip('\n'))
print('\n'.join(lines))
```

Comment: The file does not the the '\n' in them. its just a file with characters in each line, when i try this solution it does not work

Comment: Well, '\n' means the new-line character, which has to be in file if it contains more than one text line.  But it is true I made a little mistake when writing it without testing.  Try it now :)

Comment: how did you test this?

when i do it i get nothing in return. the screen doesn't print anything in the end. i grabbed what you just wrote and put it under the line that says "print("Here is your output formated to a max of", lineLength, "characters per line: ")"......ofcourse i took off the insert_newlines function

Comment: Yes, that is where it should go, instead of `insert_newlines(file, lineLength)`.  Also, you can remove line `file = openFile.read()`.

Comment: Yes, i did that, except i need file = openFile.read() because im printing original file first before printing the formated file. but if you grabbed that entire code and used it, i get nothing in return in the end.

Comment: Then reopen the file just before my code (by adding `openFile = open(filename, 'r')`).  I tested my code and both parts work.

Comment: PERFECT!, i just had to reopen it!...wow thanks alot man for helping me so much and taking all this time i really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the issue here, the code seems to work just fine:

```
def insert_newlines(string, afterEvery_char):
    lines = []
    # if len(string) is 100 and afterEvery_char is 10
    # then i will be equal to 0, 10, 20, ... 90
    # in lines we'll have [string[0:10], ..., string[90:100]] (ie the entire string)
    for i in range(0, len(string), afterEvery_char):
        lines.append(string[i:i+afterEvery_char])
        # resetting i here won't have any effect whatsoever
    print('\n'.join(lines))


>>> insert_newlines('Beautiful is better than ugly.\nExplicit is better than implicit.\nSimple is better than complex.\n..', 10)
Beautiful
is better
than ugly.

Explicit
is better
than impli
cit.
Simpl
e is bette
r than com
plex.
..
```

isn't that what you want?

Comment: It doesnt work just fine when the lines are being read from a file. When you just put the string like that into the function it seems to work but not when it is being read from a file, it cuts the ines weird

Comment: what i want is once it cuts the FIRST line, it does the same to EVERY other line after. 

Ex. if lines 1-3 have 20 chars each

when the first line is cut it will have 15 chars.
the line after that will have 5(obviously)
then the next line, which has 20 chars., will cut after 15 chars again and so on